# Can a Virtual Host on Apache access the files of another Virtual Host?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm looking to set up a few virtual hosts for different domains for a few friends, and want to know if one virtual host can access files from another host, whether it be via PHP or any other option or if it's totally isolated, so any scripts they can run would only affect their area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Apache "virtual host" is just a mapping of a hostname (or ip address or port) to a particular set of configuration directives.  There is no "containment" or isolation implied by this; everything is still running on the same host.

If you want to actually isolate applications, consider investigating container technology like Docker (or a virtual machine solution), with a front-end proxy directing traffic as necessary to the appropriate backend.

Comment: So even if the hosts each have their own www folder they'd be able to access the other folders via scripts?

Comment: That's correct.  If a script were to be compromised, an attacker would have full access to the system (presumably with the UID of whatever process the web server is running as).