# Prevent cross-site access in LAMP server

Tags: php, apache, lamp

Say we have a server with pure LAMP where we created 2 websites. One inside */var/www/site1*, another one inside */var/www/site2*

Apache's **www-data** group has read access to both directories.

And that causes a problem: /var/www/site1/grab.php (which runs through http://site1.com/grab.php) can easily read some private data from */var/www/site2/config.php* by using some

`file_get_contents("/var/www/site2/config.php");`

code inside */var/www/site1/grab.php*.

Is there Apache-layer way to prevent this?

Without using suexec or another additional installations - just with configuration tuning.

I understand that if www-data has read access to both directories and site1.com is run  by www-data, it is clear why it has an access to */var/www/site2/config.php*.

But may be there is some easy way to restrict any up directory for each website and forbid them to access any path outside from their DocumentRoot directory.

Comment: Apache's main concern is the public access to the website and limiting what files can be accessed through the 80 port, it isn't concerned with what server-side code is doing, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900956/can-a-virtual-host-on-apache-access-the-files-of-another-virtual-host